# how can i get user info by id with web service rest

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services, jboss

so i'm working on a login for a mobile app but i need a Rest web service so i can get the account of a user so i was thinking maybe i should create a web service where i get a client by id and then use that to get his account when he logs in so the only thing could do is get all client can anyone please help me i 've been struggling with this for over a month

```
@Stateless
public class PersonneService implements PersonneServiceLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="bankingApp-ejb")
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Employee addPeronne(Employee employee) {
        try {
            employee.setPassword(Utils.toMD5(employee.getPassword()));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            return null;

        }
        employee.setToken(Utils.tokenGenerator());
        em.persist(employee);
        return employee;
    }

    @Override
    public Client addClient(Client client) {
        try {
            client.setPassword(Utils.toMD5(client.getPassword()));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            return null;

        }
        client.setToken(Utils.tokenGenerator());
        em.persist(client);
        return client;
    }


    public List<Client> getListClients() {
        TypedQuery<Client> query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Client c ", Client.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }




    @Override
    public List<Employee> getListEmployees() {
        TypedQuery<Employee> query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e ", Employee.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public Personne SignIn(String email, String password) {
        System.out.println("login");
        try {
            password = Utils.toMD5(password);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            return null;
        }
        if (isExistEmail(email)) {
            Personne user = loginEmail(email, password);
            if (user != null) {
                return user;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**************** verifier l'existance d'un email  *************************/
    public boolean isExistEmail(String email) {
        long result = (long) em.createQuery("SELECT count(u) from Personne u WHERE u.email = :email")
                .setParameter("email", email).getSingleResult();

        if (result == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }



    /**************** verifier l'existance d'un utilisateur  *************************/
    public boolean isExistUsername(String username) {
        long result = (long) em.createQuery("SELECT count(u) from User u WHERE u.username = :username")
                .setParameter("username", username).getSingleResult();
        if (result == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    /*************************************  find Personne By Email and Password *****************************/
    public Personne loginEmail(String email, String password) {
        try {
            Personne result = (Personne) em
                    .createQuery("SELECT u from Personne u WHERE u.email = :email and u.password = :password")
                    .setParameter("email", email).setParameter("password", password).getSingleResult();
            return result;
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int updateClient(Client client) {
        return em.createQuery("update Client c SET c.nom = "+client.getNom()+"SET c.email ="+client.getEmail()+"SET c.telephone ="+client.getTelephone()+" WHERE c.id = "+client.getId()).executeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public int updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
        return em.createQuery("update Employee c SET c.nom = "+employee.getNom()+"SET c.email ="+employee.getEmail()+"SET c.telephone ="+employee.getTelephone()+" WHERE c.id = "+employee.getId()).executeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public int suspendClient(Client client) {
        return em.createQuery("update Client c SET c.is_suspended = false WHERE c.id = "+client.getId()).executeUpdate();
    }




}`

    @Path("/personne")
@RequestScoped
public class PersoneWS {

    @EJB
    PersonneServiceLocal personneManager;

    @Path("/client")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addClient(Client client){
        client.setDateInscription(new Date());
        System.out.println(client);
        return Response.ok(personneManager.addClient(client)).build();
    }

    @Path("/client")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getClient(){
        return Response.ok(personneManager.getListClients()).build();

    }


    @Path("/login")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response signIn(Personne user) {
        GenerateToken generateToken = new GenerateToken();
        JsonObjectBuilder jsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        if (user.getEmail() != null) {
            Personne personne = personneManager.SignIn(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());
            if(personne != null){
                jsonObject.add("token", generateToken.issueToken(personne.getEmail()));
                jsonObject.add("username", personne.getNom());
                if(personne instanceof Client)
                    jsonObject.add("type", "client");
                if(personne instanceof Employee)
                    jsonObject.add("type", "employee");
                jsonObject.add("email", personne.getEmail());
                System.out.println(jsonObject);
                return Response.ok(jsonObject.build()).build();
            }

        }
        return Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
    }

}



       @Local
    public interface PersonneServiceLocal {

        public Employee addPeronne(Employee employee);
        public Client addClient(Client client );
        public List<Client> getListClients();
        public List<Employee> getListEmployees();
        public Personne SignIn (String usernameOrEmail , String password);
        public int updateClient(Client client);
        public int updateEmployee(Employee employee);
        public int suspendClient(Client client);


    }
```

Comment: Which object contains your account details?

Comment: You need to get any user by id or user that already been logged in? If I understood you right - you need some kind of session after user login.  You can put your Employee in  ThreadLocal and then get in you application where you need it. https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-emulate-createdby-and-lastmodifiedby-from-spring-data-using-the-generatortype-hibernate-annotation/.